# How to Run this python script with Django?

Tags: python, django

// this is a matrix code of python and how should i run it in django

```
X=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
Y=[[9,8,7],[6,5,4],[3,2,1]]
result=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(X)):
        result[i][j]=X[i][j]+Y[i][j]
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "running in Django"? Do you want that final printout to be shown in a web page or what?

Answer (score 1):

You can just run it in Django like normal python code. Here is a view which returns the result you desire.

Here is your code in a Django view.

```
def matrix(request):
    X = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
    Y = [[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]
    result = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
    for i in range(len(X)):
        for j in range(len(X)):
            result[i][j] = X[i][j] + Y[i][j]
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

It outputs:

```
[10, 10, 10][10, 10, 10][10, 10, 10]
```

to the webpage.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use it in a django template, you can do that.

1. You can create a file in your application ** utils.py ** by
   example and add your code:

```py
def my_matrix():
    X=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 
    Y=[[9,8,7],[6,5,4],[3,2,1]]
    result=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
    for i in range(len(X)):
        for j in range(len(X)): result[i][j]=X[i][j]+Y[i][j]
    return result
```

Import it into your views.py and call it where you whant

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .utils import my_matrix

def home(request):
   result_matrix = my_matrix()
   context = {
    'data_matrix': result_matrix,
   }
   return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

normally you can display or use it in your template.

2. You can directly use it in your view

```py
def home(request):
   X=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 
   Y=[[9,8,7],[6,5,4],[3,2,1]]
   result=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
   for i in range(len(X)):
     for j in range(len(X)): result[i][j]=X[i][j]+Y[i][j]
   context = {
    'data_matrix': result,
   }
   return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```